# How to use an initializer_list to create a C++ <array> of structures?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

The following code works as expected to initialize a vector of structs:

```
#include <array>
struct node
{
    std::string name;
    std::string value;
};

const std::vector<node> reqFields ({
    { "query", tmpEmail },
    { "firstname", firstName },
    { "lastname", lastName }
});
```

I want to optimize my code a bit to use a C++ 11 array instead, given that my data is static. However, the following won't compile:

```
const std::array<node, 3>({
    { "query", tmpEmail },
    { "firstname", firstName },
    { "lastname", lastName }
});
```

What is the right syntax to initialize the array? or maybe this is something that Visual Studio 15 has trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) has a constructor that takes `initializer_list` :

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init,
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

but [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is an aggregate and follows the rules of [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) .

So you need to switch from `()` to `{}`

```
const std::array<node, 3> reqFields {
    {{ "query", "tmp" },
    { "firstname", "firstName" },
    { "lastname", "lastName" }}
};
```

[see it live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/H0XZqo).